# Table row disappear when creating tablesorter pagination

Tags: php, jquery, pagination, tablesorter

I want to create pagination for my tablesorter tables. However my pagination not working but the prev,next button are there. Only its not functioning. Whenever I try to to remove `$(Document).ready.....` it worked but all my data row is disappear. It just blank and only the only thing left is my table header and that pagination button. Is there something wrong with my code?

This is my index.php

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.tablesorter.pager.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<!----
---->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script> 
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> -->



    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            $("#myTable")
            .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
            .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")}); 
        } 
        ); 
    </script>

    </head>

    <?php 

        // First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
        require("common.php"); 

    ?>

    <form class="login, reminder">
            <h1>Search your data...</h1>
    <p style="text-align: center">Enter your search here: <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Enter your search here">&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Select education level: <select id="edulevel">
    <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
    <option value="PHD">PHD</option>
    <option value="MASTER">MASTER</option>
    <option value="DEGREE">DEGREE</option></select></p>    
    <div id="contentBox" class="login, reminder" style="margin:0px auto; width:95%; overflow-y: auto; height:304px;">


    <div id="result" class="login"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        /*
        setInterval(function(){
            //alert('Refreshing database');
            $("#result").load("res.php", "update=true").fadeIn("slow").text("Refreshing Database");
        }, 10000);
        */


        function update() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'userres.php',
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(data) {
                    if (parseInt(data) == 0) {
                        $("#result").css({ color: "red" }).text("offline");
                    } else {
                        $("#result").css({ color: "green" }).text("online");
                    }
                }
            });    // properly end the ajax() invocation
        }


        function ajaxSearchUpdater(){
            $("#result").show();
            var x = $("#search").val();
            var y = $("#edulevel").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'userres.php',
                data:'q='+x+'&e='+y,
                cache:false,
                success:function(data){
                    $("#result").html(data)
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            ajaxSearchUpdater();               // fires on document.ready
            $("#search").keyup(function() {
                ajaxSearchUpdater();           // your function call
            });
            $("#edulevel").click(function() {
                ajaxSearchUpdater();           // your function call
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is where my table is userres.php

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.tablesorter.pager.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<!----
---->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable")
        .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
        .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")}); 
    } 
    ); 
</script>

</head>

<?php

require("common.php"); 
error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE );


//print_r($_GET);
$q=$_POST['q'];
if(isset($_POST['e'])){
    $e=$_POST['e'];
    //echo $q;
    //echo $e;
}

echo '<div id="pager" class="pager">
    <form>
        <img src="css/first.png" class="first"/>
        <img src="css/prev.png" class="prev"/>
        <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>
        <img src="css/next.png" class="next"/>
        <img src="css/last.png" class="last"/>
        <select class="pagesize">
            <option value="">LIMIT</option>
            <option value="2">2 per page</option>
            <option value="5">5 per page</option>
            <option value="10">10 per page</option>

        </select>
    </form>
</div>';

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    $r=$stmt->fetchAll();
    echo "<table class='tablesorter-blackice' id='myTable' style='width:97%; table-border: 1'>";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>No.</th>";
        echo "<th>No.Matric</th>";
        echo "<th>Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Programme</th>";
        echo "<th>Title</th>";
        echo "<th>Education Level</th>";
        echo "<th>Serial Number</th>";
        echo "<th>Availability</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";

    foreach($r as $row){

            echo "<tr align='center'><td>". ($a+1) ."</td><td>". $row['matricno'] ."</td><td>". $row['studentname'] ."</td><td>". $row['programme'] ."</td><td>". $row['title'] ."</td><td>". $row['education_level'] ."</td><td>". $row['serialno'] ."</td><td>". $row['bavailable'] ."</td></tr>";
            $a++;
            //echo $row['education_level'];
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
}
else{
    echo "<p align='center'>Nothing to show you :( I am really sorry for this T_T </p>";
}

?>
```

I don't have any problem with databases. Only that it happen when I remove the `$(Document).ready....` from the function because some tutorial not using that and some does. Any clue what I miss?
*NOTE I am intentionly not included my query because too many comment and stuff. Also, I call tablesorter on both page is because I am not sure which page should call tablesorter function. It's because my table is on php file. not html

Comment: The document ready function wrapper is only necessary if the javascript is loaded or executed anywhere above the bottom of the page. When the `#result` container is updated, is the table inside of it?

Answer (score 0):

I already solve it by creating it manually inside the userres.php. I think that its not working is because since I'm using Ajax in index.php to request data from userres.php. Therefore the data being return is become DOM which is Document Object Model and it has related with HTML (If anyone can clarify this better than me, i would be happy). So I have to create manual like this. (mathematical stuff T_T)

Starting after the execution of the query inside userres.php

```
$stmt2 = $db->prepare($totalrow); 
$stmt2->bindValue(':q','%'.$q.'%');
$stmt2->bindValue(':e',$e);
$stmt2->execute();

$row = $stmt2->rowCount();

$limitrow = 1;
if(isset($_POST['pagelim'])){
    $limitrow = $_POST['pagelim'];

    if($limitrow == 0){
        $limitrow = $row;
    }

}


if($row != 0){
    $baki = $row%$limitrow;
}
else{
    $baki = 0;
    $limitrow = 1;
    $row = 1;
}

$maxpage = (($row-$baki)/$limitrow);
$startrow = $limitrow*($pageno-1);

if($baki!=0)
    $maxpage++;
```

----then another query---- i exclude the query

Code below is to animate the page number a bit and customize it.

```
$startPage = ($pageno <5) ? 1 : $pageno -4;
$endPage = 8 + $startPage;
$endPage = ($maxpage < $endPage) ? $maxpage : $endPage;
$diff = $startPage - $endPage + 8;
$startPage -=($startPage - $diff > 0) ? $diff : 0;

$a = $startPage;
echo "<ol id='olpoint'>";


if($startPage > 1) echo "<a href='#' onclick='ajaxSearchUpdater(1);'><li>First</li></a>";

while($a<=$endPage){

        echo "<a href='#' onclick='ajaxSearchUpdater(".$a.");'";
        if($pageno == $a){
            echo "style='color:grey;'";
        }   
        echo "><li>".$a."</li></a>";
        $a++;
};

if($endPage < $maxpage) echo "<a href='#' onclick='ajaxSearchUpdater(".$maxpage.");'><li>End</li></a>";

echo "</ol>";
```

For my index.php i put it like this

```
function ajaxSearchUpdater(p){
        $("#result").show();
        var x = $("#search").val();
        var y = $("#edulevel").val();
        var pagelim = $("#pagefpe").val();
        var pagenumber = p;

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'userres.php',
            data:'q='+x+'&e='+y+'&pagelim='+pagelim+'&pageno='+pagenumber,
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){
                $("#result").html(data)
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        ajaxSearchUpdater(1);               // fires on document.ready
        $("#search").keyup(function() {
            ajaxSearchUpdater(1);           // your function call
        });
        $("#edulevel").click(function() {
            ajaxSearchUpdater(1);           // your function call
        });
        $("#pagefpe").click(function() {
            ajaxSearchUpdater(1);           // your function call
        });
    });
```

NOTE: I may not say this is the best solution in terms of performance because even myself not knowing much about Ajax and DOM stuff. Also, inside of this userres.php, i use a lot of query and inside the query there is another query. So i think its not good right. The point is I need to make this pagination to work regardless the performance but if there is much better way, i hope anyone can provide more :).